# select2 options don't load

Tags: php, prepared-statement, jquery-select2

I have a list of options which is loaded via select2. It worked perfectly. Then I changed the query for security reasons to prepared statements. After that the options weren’t loaded anymore. Is there a known bug with prepared statements? What am I doing wrong?
This is the code:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=eventdb;charset=utf8', 'root', 
'');
$dbh -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT ed_020_bereich.ED_KBID, ed_020_bereich.BR_Bereich
    FROM ed_020_bereich
    WHERE ed_020_bereich.BR_active = 1 AND ed_020_bereich.ED_KID = :ED_KID
    ORDER BY ed_020_bereich.BR_Bereich";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':ED_KID', $kunde);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$return = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $return[]=$row;
}
```

Comment: Double check that all variables contains what you expect (where's `$kunde` defined?). There's no know "bug" that would cause a valid SQL statement to not work. It would have been a very well known issue. Also, check if `$return` contains what you expect.

Comment: Can you show what it was so we can compare the two.

Comment: Thanks guy for the help. I found the error. It was my fault. There was a flaw in the return statement.